# Perl - Spreadsheet::XLSX refer to a specific sheet in the workbook

Tags: perl

Still learning to walk (crawl?) in Perl.

I have the Perl code where I am basically trying to loop through array strings and find those sheets in my workbook (for right now, I am 100% certain there will be a sheet with the names provided in my workbook). The $worksheet variable seems to be assigned to the worksheet just fine based on the

```
print $worksheet->(Name);
```

test line. However, the next line

```
my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell(1,1);
```

does not seem to be setting the cell, for the following lines do not print the cell value (which I know is set for this case). I know this because if I comment out the "if ($cell)" in

```
my $value = $cell->value() if ($cell);
```

I get the error:

```
Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at script.pl line 14
```

Full code is here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;

my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('C:\Scott.xlsm',);
my @sheets = qw(Fund_Data GL_Data);

foreach my $sheet (@sheets) {
    my $worksheet = $excel->Worksheet($sheet);
    print $worksheet->{Name}, "\n"; #just a test to make it is being set to worksheet
    my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell(1,1);
    my $value = $cell->value() if ($cell);
    print $value, "\n" if ($value);
}
```

my results are simply:

```
Fund_Data
GL_Data
```

When they should be

```
Fund_Data
you '--> (Range("A1").Value in Sheet("Fund_Data"))
GL_Data
me '--> (Range("A1").Value in Sheet("GL_Data"))
```

Also, my basis for building the code above was off the code below, which is tried and tested. The main difference in the code above is, instead of looping through each sheet, i am attempting to assign the sheets I want based on the array values.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;

my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('P:\VBA\Help\Book3.xlsx',);

foreach my $sheet (@{$excel -> {Worksheet}}) {
    printf("Sheet:  %s\n", $sheet->{Name});
    my $cell = $sheet->get_cell(2,1);
    my $value = $cell->value();
    printf("Cell value is: $value");
}
```

Comment: Do `use Data::Dumper;print Dumper($cell) . "\n";` just after you initialize `$cell`.  What is printed out?

Comment: @JackManey -> so that officially tells me the cell is not getting set, but my question are why not? and how do I get it set?

Comment: Well, try dumping out `$worksheet` and see what cells it has.

Comment: genuis! solved. I dumped the $worksheet and found out that the cell references are zero based, so referring to cell A1 needs to be Cell(0,0) not Cell(1,1)! I will update answer my own question below. Wish I could give you points for solving the Q with your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @JackManey 's comments above, I used Data::Dumper on $Worksheet and got the following result (partial result):

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'DefColWidth' => '8.43
                 'MinCol' => 0,
                 'MaxRow' => 25,
                 'MinRow' => 0,
                 'path' => 'worksheets/
                 'MaxCol' => 0,
                 'Name' => 'Fund_Data',
```

'MinCol' => 0, 'MinRow' => 0, tipped me off to the fact that my cell references are zero based. When I changed

```
my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell(1,1);
```

to

```
my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell(0,0);
```

I got the results I wanted!

Not only did I get my Q answered, I learned an awesome built-in PERL function!

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to accept this answer (by clicking on the outline of a check mark below the upvote/downvote arrows).