# Perl - Code Enhancement

Tags: perl

I've just started coding in Perl and am just looking to find out if the code below can be made more efficient or can be done in fewer lines.

I've researched a bit into the [`Win32::OLE`](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aOLE) module and the [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) module, but this seemed the way to go from what I read so far.

This question is basically a newbie asking an elder: "Hey, how do I become a better Perl progammer?"

The purpose of the code is to obtain data from specified ranges in specified sheets of an Excel workbook and write the contents of those ranges to CSV files.

Also, I know I need to implement general checks, like making sure the my `$cellValue` is defined before adding it to the array and such, but I am looking more for overall structure. Like is there a way to flatten the looping by putting all the whole row into an array at once, or the whole range in an array or reference, or something of that nature?

Thanks

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;

my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('C:\scott.xlsm',);
my @sheets = qw(Fund_Data GL_Data);

foreach my $sheet (@sheets) {

    my $worksheet = $excel->Worksheet($sheet);
    my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell(25,0);

    if ($cell) { # make sure cell value isn't blank
        my $myFile = "C:/$sheet.csv";
        open NEWFILE, ">$myFile" or die $!;

        # write all cells from Range("A25:[MaxColumn][MaxRow]") to a csv file
        my $maxCol = $worksheet->{MaxCol};
        my $maxRow = $worksheet->{MaxRow};
        my @arrRows;
        my $rowString;

        # loop through each row and column in defined range and string together each row and write to file
        foreach my $row (24 .. $maxRow) {

            foreach my $col (0 .. $maxCol) {

                my $cellValue = $worksheet->{Cells} [$row] [$col]->Value();

                if ($rowString) {
                    $rowString = $rowString . "," . $cellValue;
                } else {
                    $rowString = $cellValue;
                }
            }

            print NEWFILE "$rowString\n";
            undef $rowString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, your code is already very good for a non-expert! There are things you can do to make it more idiomatic (see the answers), but it's an excellent start!

Comment: @DVK +1 for the encouragement. Thank you. Good to know I am off to good start.

Comment: Since this is not a real question, IMHO it would have fitted better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about codereview.stackexchange. will go there next time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mark's suggestion is an excellent one. Another minor improvement would be to replace "Do a bunch of nested logic `if $cell`, with "don't do anything `unless $cell` - this way you have slightly more readable code (remove 1 extra indentation/nested block; AND don't have to worry what happens if $cell is empty.

```
# OLD
foreach my $sheet (@sheets) {
    my $worksheet = $excel->Worksheet($sheet);
    my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell(25,0);

    if ($cell) { # make sure cell value isn't blank
        # All your logic in the if
    }
}

# NEW
foreach my $sheet (@sheets) {
    my $worksheet = $excel->Worksheet($sheet);
    next unless $worksheet->get_cell(25,0); # You don't use $cell, so dropped

    # All your logic that used to be in the if
}
```

---

As you noted, `Text::CSV` would be a good thing to consider, depending on whether your data ever needs to be quoted based on CSV standard (e.g. contains spaces, commas, quotes etc...). If it may need to be quoted, don't re-invent the wheel, and use `Text::CSV` for printing instead. Untested example would be something like this:

```
# At the start of the script:
use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { } ); # Add error handler!

    # In the loop, when the file handle $fh is opened
    foreach my $row (24 .. $maxRow) {
        my $cols = [ map { $worksheet->{Cells}[$row][$_] } 0 .. $maxCol) ];
        my $status = $csv->print ($fh, $cols);
        # Error handling
    }
```

Comment: BTW, AFAIR, you may possibly need to replace your manually opened file handle with a `IO::File` object for `Text::CSV` to work

Comment: Thanks for the help with TEXT::CSV. I was thinking it would be handy to help write the data to the file correctly. Now, I can see how it can be done, whereas before I was struggling.

Comment: @Scott - `SYNOPSYS` section of POD help on CPAN is your best first approach in cases like this.

Answer (score 6):

No reason to have that inner loop:

```
print NEWFILE join(",", map { $worksheet->{Cells}[$row][$_] } 0 .. $maxCol), "\n";
```

Also, make sure you have your indexes correct.  I'm not familiar with Spreadsheet::XLSX, so make sure that max col & row are zero based like the rest of your code.  If they're not then you'll want to iterate over `0 .. $maxCol-1`.

Comment: Which version of Perl is using map?

Comment: @Mark Mann - now that is sweet! Thank you.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus - at the very least, Perl 4 and older (meaning, any Perl since at least 1991). Probably even earlier but I'm too much of a newbie to have used Perl 3

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking of getting a more up-to-date text book.

Comment: @Mark Mann - Also, thanks for zero based comment. Spreadsheet::XLSX does use zero base. I found that out the hard way. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725122/perl-spreadsheetxlsx-refer-to-a-specific-sheet-in-the-workbook

Answer (score 4):

I would advise against hard coding file names... especially in small projects like this, get in the habit of passing the file names in via `GetOpt::Long`. If you do that habitually with all of your small projects, it makes it much easier to remember to do it right when it counts on a larger project.

Your code is well structured and readable, and you anticipated the problems with your loop statements, you used warnings and strict, and you're generally using libraries the right way.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, your code is clear and well-structured. But I think it could be improved with a little more Perlishness.

The following points come to mind

- Use lexical filehandles and the three-parameter form of `open` (`open my $newfile, '>', $myFile`)
- Iterate over hash or array values (or *slices* of them) rather than their keys or indexes, unless you really need the keys for the body of the loop
- Extract pointers to data substructures within a loop if that is the focus of the loop (`my $rows = $worksheet->{Cells}`)
- Spot where you are using a loop to transform one list into another, and use `map` instead

I hope I haven't jumped the gun a bit by writing a solution using using `Text::CSV` as you proposed. With luck this is instructive for you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::XLSX;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;

my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX->new('C:\scott.xlsm',);

foreach my $sheet (qw/ Fund_Data  GL_Data /) {

  my $worksheet = $excel->Worksheet($sheet);
  next unless $worksheet->get_cell(25,0);

  my $myFile = "C:\\$sheet.csv";
  open my $newfile, '>', $myFile or die $!;

  my $rows = $worksheet->{Cells};

  # Write all cells from row 25 onwards to the CSV file

  foreach my $row (@{$rows}[24..$#{$rows}]) {
    my @values = map $_ ? $_->Value : '', @$row;
    $csv->print($newfile, \@values);
    print $newfile "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: bang up job on this. I really like this code. Some many answers to choose from... if I could I would accept this as answer as well. Not fully sure how it works in the foreach loop at bottom, but it will give something to learn!